# How to put a fixed height on a table cell first?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

how do you put a fixed height on a cell without affecting the resize of a cell? I figured out how to resize the table cell but when I want to put a button it looks small so I want to put a fixed size height on the cell first, then once the content gets big is should follow the resize method.
These are the resize method.
Thank you in advance

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}
```

---

```
     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
        textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -10)
        ])

     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.bottomAnchor, constant: 50),
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),
        button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 20),
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10)
        ])
```

Comment: show how you set the constraints

Comment: On the table view or on the cell

Comment: constraints of cell

Answer (score 0):

Default behaviour of `UITableView` will handle it on its own.

Make sure that you didn't set anything custom for table view. Second thing is `UITableViewCell` where you need to specify height for each UI component - this will allow `UITableView` to resize cell properly.

Edit.1

If you are creating your view controller from xib/storyboard, then you would need just do this for your tableView (notice that cell is loaded from nib and view controller conforms `UITableViewDataSource`)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "YourCellNibName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
}
```

Comment: can you provide code please, I used custom tableview cell in order to put buttons etc on the tableview cell

Comment: I had edited answer to paste you readable code block. Are creating a cell from interface builder? Can you share constraints of your cell?

Comment: Table view or cell?because the cell constraints I already posted. Also I am not creating a cell from interface builder.

Comment: What you want to do is to define initial height of textView with possibility to resize, like this textView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 50)

Answer (score 0):

You have a height conflict because of these 3 constraints

```
 textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
 button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.bottomAnchor, constant: 50),
 button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),
```

You need to also add the textView & button to contentView and set the constraints with it

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10), 
    textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
    textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10), 
    textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:50),

    button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.textView.bottomAnchor, constant: 50),
    button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor),
    button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 20),
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10)
])
```

Comment: Thanks you @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {     // First table cell
        if firstLoad {
            return 200  // Fixed height 
        } else {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }
    }   
}
```

Also you might need to re-trigger the heightForRowAt method by doing

```swift
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

set the bottom `constraint` of the button to the bottom `constraint` of the cell `contentView`.
The `autolayout` will automatically manage the cell height.